The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Tablet_API_35 has terminated
Hi guys,
I’m encountering an issue with the Android emulator. When I try to run the AVD (Pixel_Tablet_API_35), I receive the error message: "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Tablet_API_35 has terminated."
Here are the steps I’ve already tried to resolve the issue:
1.I checked the "Turn Windows features on or off" and ensured all necessary features are enabled.
enter image description here
2.I confirmed that SVM mode is enabled in the BIOS.
3.I made sure that all SDK tools are installed and up to date.
enter image description here
here are the my laptop specifications:
RAM: 16 GB
Storage: 38 GB free
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H
GPU: GeForce 3060
OS: Windows11
I would appreciate any advice on how to resolve this issue. Thank you for your guys help TuT
I tried launching the AVD with the settings I configured and expected it to run without any errors. However, instead of starting, the emulator process terminated unexpectedly. I was hoping to see the emulator interface for testing my Android application, but I only received the termination error message.

I needed an ARM-based emulator because I had some issues with the dargon2 and got the same error.
The issue was that I have a x86 architecture for my laptop and the emulator an ARM.
(There could have been also performance issues, I activated the Windows Hypervisor and still didn't work. I tried that before running the emulator from the command shell)
You can run the emulator from the command shell and will tell you the reason, as for example:
"PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host."
Was hard to find the path to the emulator, as this is being saved in the hidden folders and in case it helps, the path to the emulator should be:
C:\Users*yourusername*\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
and the command shall be: .\emulator -avd Pixel_Tablet_API_35
